# Need to get text of a specific tag

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, gettext, getattribute

I want to get the text of the `<b>` tag. But in XPath, the ID value is dynamic. I tried the below code. But it is not working

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(text(), 'Test Subject ST1')]")
WebElement messageHeader;

@FindBy(xpath = "//*b[text()='Test Subject ST1']")
WebElement messageHeader;
```

[image]

Comment: Try this `.//b[normalize-space(.) = 'Test Subject ST1']` and let me know..

Comment: Saurabh, It is not working. Still I am getting empty string.

Comment: Could you share how you are getting the text of this element??

Comment: `code`                                                                                               @FindBy(xpath = ".//b[normalize-space(.) = 'Test Subject ST1']")
 WebElement messageHeader;                                                               String subject_actual = messageHeader.getText();
  if (subject_actual.equalsIgnoreCase(subject))
  {
   System.out.println(subject_actual);
   System.out.println("True");
   return true;
  }
  else
  {
   System.out.println("False");
  }

Comment: try as `String subject_actual = messageHeader.getAttribute("innerHTML")` ans let me know..

Comment: Saurabh, Awesome!!! Working fine..Thanks...

Comment: I have provided it as answer, you can mark it as [correct answer as well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to help some other for same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If unfortunately [`WebElement#getText()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText--) doesn't work due to designing issue or some thing other reason, Try using [`WebElement#getAttribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-) as below :-

```
@FindBy(xpath = ".//b[normalize-space(.) = 'Test Subject ST1']") 
WebElement messageHeader; 

String subject_actual = messageHeader.getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

or

```
String subject_actual = messageHeader.getAttribute("textContent");
```